# Cannot add CCNode to Scene

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccnode

I have the IntroScene, and I wanna add a node, but it doesn't seem to work. Here are two different ways I tried doing it, and BOTH failed.

First way, failed:

in hearts2.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Hearts2 : CCNode {

}

@end
```

in hearts2.m

```
#import "Hearts2.h"


@implementation Hearts2

@end
```

in IntroLayer.m

```
- (id)init
{
// Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
self = [super init];
if (!self) return(nil);

heart2 *heart;
[self addChild:heart z:2];

// done
return self;
}
```

I didn't expect that to work (actually I was desperate and tried it that way as the second way just to see if it would work). The actual first attempt I tried to do was this, and it also Failed:

in hearts1.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Hearts1 : CCNode

+ (Hearts1 *)node;
- (id)init;
-(void)selfAnimate;



@end
```

in hearts1.m

```
#import "Hearts1.h"

@implementation Hearts1 {
}

+ (Hearts1 *)node
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);


    return self;

}
- (void)dealloc
{
}

- (void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

}

- (void)onExit
{
    // always call super onExit last
    [super onExit];
}



- (void)selfAnimate
{
}
@end
```

in IntroLayer.m

```
- (id)init
{
// Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
self = [super init];
if (!self) return(nil);

heart1 *heart;
[self addChild:heart z:2];

// done
return self;
}
```

Please, I would do anything if someone could help me figure this out thanks everyone very much. I always get the SigABRT so I have no idea what is going wrong. I'm sure I'm just stupid and don't know how to code and missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
heart2 *heart;
```

You named your class `Hearts2` so use the exact same name, including uppercase.

Secondly you created a variable but this will be nil. If you aren't using ARC (which you should) this will create an uninitialized object.

This will create an instance of `Hearts2`, assign it to the local var `heart` and add it as a child:

```
Hearts2 *heart = [Hearts2 node];
[self addChild:heart z:2];
```

Comment: Excellent !! I added `Hearts2 *heart = [Hearts2 node];` and actually even both ways work thank u...